# How to draw a paragraph on canvas of a customview for android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am having large amount of text to be drawn on canvas..I am able to set the text but all the text is displaying in a single line.so i cant able to read all the text..I want to set the text as a paragraph on canvas .could any one tell me the approach to do this functionality.

I tried use getLineCount(),getLineBound() but it is prompting error on those lines since my view does not contains those methods.

Comment: Try this for new line \n or /n

Comment: @Bigflow can we set it dynamically

Comment: What happends now if you type in a long text? It makes a horizontal scroll?

Comment: No i dont a horizontal scroll..I have to implement it on pagecurl @Bigflow

Comment: Try in layout: `android:maxEms` to specify a maximum amount of characters in conjunction with `android:singleLine="false"`

Answer (score 2):

You may have to find the longest sub-string that can be accommodated within your canvas width and repeat this until your entire "lengthy" string has been broken into smaller strings. Recursion helps here

You can try something like this:

```
class Font
{
    private TextPaint tp = new TextPaint();
    private Paint p = new Paint();

    int getCharWidth(char ch, int fontSize)
    {
        tp.setTextSize(fontSize);
        Rect r = new Rect();
        tp.getTextBounds(String.valueOf(ch), 0, 1, r);
        return r.width();
    }

    int getHeight(int fontSize)
    {
        tp.setTextSize(fontSize);
        Rect r = new Rect();
        tp.getTextBounds(String.valueOf('A'), 0, 1, r);
        return r.height();
    }

    int getStringWidth(String str, int fontSize)
    {
        p.setTextSize(fontSize);
        tp.setTextSize(fontSize);
        Rect r = new Rect();
        tp.getTextBounds(str, 0, str.length(), r);          
        return r.width();//you may also try p.measureText(str);
    }
}

public String getLongestSubString(int width, int fontSize, String text)
{   
    int maxCharPerLine = width / (new Font()).getCharWidth('A', fontSize);
    int stringWidth = (new Font()).getStringWidth(text, fontSize);
    int posOfSpace = text.lastIndexOf(' ');
    if( stringWidth <= width || maxCharPerLine >= text.length())
        return text;
    String temp = text.substring(0, (posOfSpace == -1) ? (maxCharPerLine > text.length() ? text.length() : maxCharPerLine) : posOfSpace);
    return getLongestSubString(width, fontSize, temp);
}

public ArrayList<String> breakTextToLines(int width, int fontSize, String text)
{
    if(text == null)
        return null;
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    text = text.replace("\n", " ");

    int length = -1;
    String tempText = "";

    do
    {
        if( !tempText.endsWith(" ") && tempText.length() > 0)
            length += tempText.length();
        else
            length += tempText.length() + 1;

        if( length >= text.length())
            break;

        tempText = getLongestSubString(width, fontSize, text.substring(length));
        lines.add(tempText);
    }
    while(length < text.length());

    return lines;
}
```

Now once you have the list of strings (using the method `breakTextToLines(int,int,String)`) broken to smaller strings that can now fit within the canvas, you can start your drawing process something like below

```
int fontSize = 20;
float lineSpaceFactor = 0.5f;
int lineHeight = (new Font()).getHeight(fontSize);
int lineSpace = (int)(lineSpaceFactor * lineHeight);

int width = 256;//your canvas width can go here
int height = 256;//your canvas height can go here
String string = "Need a lengthy string? why not Dr Zoidberg maybe? woop woop woop!!!";//your lengthy string can go here
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);//your canvas or bitmap source goes here
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
paint.setTextSize(fontSize);

ArrayList<String> lines = breakTextToLines(width, fontSize, string);
int numOfLines = lines.size();
int overallHeight = numOfLines * (lineHeight + lineSpace);

int yLoc = (height - overallHeight) / 2;
yLoc += lineSpace;

for(String line : lines)
{
    int xLoc = textureWidth /2 ;       
    canvas.drawText(text, xLoc, yLoc, paint);

    yLoc += (lineHeight + lineSpace);       
}
//your canvas would now be drawn with the paragraph broken into lines and centre aligned
```

Hope this helps.